# React setState in promise causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

#### Expected

When `fetchServices()` is called, `api.getServices` is called and in the promise `this.setState` is called to change `fetchingServices` to `false`. Which then hides the loading spinner animation.

#### Results

For some reason the App is stuck in an infinite loop:

[image]

#### In my ServicesContainer

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    services: props.state.servicesReducer.services,
    fetchingServices: true,
    addingService: false
  }
  this.fetchServices = this.fetchServices.bind(this);
}
```

#### The return()

```
return (
  <div className='services-container'>
    <ul className='services-list'>
      <li>
        <AddServiceContainer />
      </li>
      { this.state.fetchingServices
          ? <div className="icon-spin5 animate-spin"></div>
          : null }

      { this.fetchServices() }
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

#### Finally fetchServices()

```
fetchServices() {
  console.log('fetchServices')
  api.getServices(12345).then(res => {
    console.log(' api.getServices res:', res)

    this.setState({
      fetchingServices: false
    });
  });
}
```

**Full code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { AddServiceContainer } from './AddServiceContainer'
import { ServiceCard } from '../../components'
import { getServices } from '../../actions'
import * as api from '../../services/api'

export class ServicesContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            services: props.state.servicesReducer.services,
            fetchingServices: true,
            addingService: false
        }
        this.fetchServices = this.fetchServices.bind(this);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e, user) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.searchUser(user)
    }

    fetchServices() {
        console.log('fetchServices')
        api.getServices(12345).then(res => {
            console.log(' api.getServices res:', res)

            this.setState({
              fetchingServices: false
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='services-container'>
                <ul className='services-list'>
                    <li>
                        <AddServiceContainer />
                    </li>
                    { this.state.fetchingServices
                            ? <div className="icon-spin5 animate-spin"></div>
                            : null }

                    { this.fetchServices() }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getServices: (services) => { dispatch(getServices(services)) }
    }
}

const ServicesListContainer = ServicesContainer;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ServicesListContainer)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you do setState, the render method is called again. Now problem here is that you are calling `fetchServices()` method inside the render method. Now whenever `fetchServices()` is called it calls an api. When the result of the api come, you are setting the state using `setState`, which causes rerender(i.e. your render method is called again), which calls the `fetchServices()` again. This is why it is going in infinite loop.

The solution: You should call your `fetchServices()` in componentWillMount/componentDidMount method like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { AddServiceContainer } from './AddServiceContainer'
import { ServiceCard } from '../../components'
import { getServices } from '../../actions'
import * as api from '../../services/api'

export class ServicesContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            services: props.state.servicesReducer.services,
            fetchingServices: true,
            addingService: false
        }
        this.fetchServices = this.fetchServices.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       this.fetchServices();
    }
    onFormSubmit(e, user) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.searchUser(user)
    }

    fetchServices() {
        console.log('fetchServices')
        api.getServices(12345).then(res => {
            console.log(' api.getServices res:', res)

            this.setState({
              fetchingServices: false
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='services-container'>
                <ul className='services-list'>
                    <li>
                        <AddServiceContainer />
                    </li>
                    { this.state.fetchingServices
                            ? <div className="icon-spin5 animate-spin"></div>
                            : null }

                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getServices: (services) => { dispatch(getServices(services)) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should never fetch data in render function. You should do it in componentDidMount function.

render is called after each state or props change, and if you execute an api call in render function, it will trigger setState and by doing so - render again and again and again...

See [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)